# Form not posting to delete SQL Object

Tags: php

I have a page to manage the users and it retrieves users fine but when I try to remove a user nothing happens.

I'm running on php 7.2 with apache2. I've checked logs and nothing breaks or gives a warning/info level. I've tried switching the query and variables and the location however it doesn't seem to take effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","user","pass","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$query = "SELECT `id`,`username`,`email`,`created_at`,`is_admin` FROM users ";


$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);


//if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if (empty($_POST["id"])) {
    $error = "Make a Selection";
  } else {
    $delete_id = test_input($_POST["id"]);
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM users WHERE id='$delete_id'");
    echo "<p>" . var_dump($sql) . "</p>";
    if($sql){
        echo "Deleted";
    }
  }
}

?>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
        font: 14px sans-serif;
         }
        .wrapper{
         width: 350px;
         vertical-align: middle;
         padding: 20px;
         }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<table border='1'><tr><th></th><th>username</th><th>email</th><th>date joined</th><th>Permissions</th></tr>
<?php
while($row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
  $id = $row['id'];
    if ($row['is_admin'] == 1) {
    $permissions ="Admin";
  }
  else {
    $permissions = "User";
 } 
  echo "<tr>";
  echo '<td><input type="checkbox"  name="ID" value="' . $id . '"></td>';
  echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['created_at'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $permissions . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }


echo "</table>";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<BR>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete"> &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp';
echo '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reset PW"><BR/><BR />';
echo "</form>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the user selected to be deleted but the deletion doesn't happen

Comment: Has any error occurred? if yes.post it here

Comment: Replace `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")` with `if (isset ($_POST)`

Comment: Why are you outputting a table in the `<head>` of an html document?

Comment: No errors occur. Nothing in the apache logs either.

Comment: @cteski probably because i forgot to end tag :) or accidentally removed it.

Comment: can u var_dump($sql)

Comment: @a.El-zahaby changing that creates a parse error  PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /var/www/html/manageusers.php on line 17,

Comment: Simply put, your HTML isn't valid.  You have a `form` tag (and others) before your `DOCTYPE` and `html` tags.  I strongly suggest you look into using an MVC framework, as mixing PHP and HTML like this often leads to easily-avoidable errors.

Comment: @Ericrs sorry i have forgot lst `)`.. this is the right  `if (isset ($_POST))`

Comment: @user3407086 when pressing delete nothing occurs with  echo "<p>" . var_dump($sql) . "</p>" ;

Comment: @A.El-zahaby thanks I can't believe I didn't catch that either. however it still didn't work.

Comment: @PatrickQ thanks. I've been editting this for so long everything is all over the place but it doesn't work. I've been interested in a MVC Framework but as I'm a 1 man show right now and the company won't be paying for it I've been kind of patching things together. Do you have an MVC you recommend? I've looked at CodeIgniter and CakePHP

Comment: @Ericrs if the var_dump is empty it means you aren't reaching that query. Have you tried replacing if `($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {` with `if (isset ($_POST))` as someone has a;ready mentioned?

Comment: @Ericrs It's really just a matter of preference.  If I had to choose one to use, I'd probably pick ZendFramework.  But that's only because it's the one I know the best, so using it over others would drastically reduce implementation time.  There's nothing particularly special about any of them vs another in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: @user3407086 yes I've tried and it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
replace:
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
with:
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

and add `name="submit"` to your submit button

Comment: I've updated the codeblock above with everyones recommendations. still nothing

Comment: @Ericrs try deleting the if empty statement and placing the delete code in the `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` code block directly. If it works it may lead us in the right direction

Comment: That got us somewhere. It now shows the sql dump which says Bool(True)

Comment: looks like the last part was the capitalization of ID so I changed that and it seems to work. I'll add a refresh to the table after 5 seconds and it should be good to go.   echo '<td><input type="checkbox"  name="ID" value="' . $id . '"></td>';

Thank you for the help